# glassfish master password error

Tags: glassfish, ubuntu-16.04

Here is what I git when I try to change master password...I have tried almost every combination of characters, numbers, special charaters
    /home/larry$ /home/glassfish/bin/asadmin change-master-password --
    savemasterpassword=true
    Enter the current master password>
    Enter the new master password> 
    Enter the new master password again> 
    Error changing master password( Error changing password for password 
    alias store /home/glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain-
    passwords( java.io.EOFException ) )

Answer (score 1):

You can try following command:

`asadmin change-master-password --savemasterpassword=true domain1`

When you are promted for the current password use 'changeit'.

Comment: I decided to not put glassfish on my laptop...I am going to finish building a server and I will put it there...Thanks for the reply I will keep it in mind

Answer (score 0):

I had changed the master password to something different than changeit but forgot to use the `--savemasterpassword=true` parameter. Then I tried to change it again and use the parameter, but I kept getting `"Error changing password"`

The solution that worked for me was to delete the file `domains\domain1\config\domain-passwords`. After that, the change-master-password command worked fine.