# Trying to startup Eclipse GlassFish 5.1.0 - suggested master password does not work

Tags: glassfish

From

- [Eclipse GlassFish - Downloads](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.glassfish/downloads)

Exists available:

1. Eclipse GlassFish 5.1.0
2. Eclipse GlassFish 5.1.0 Web Profile

Working with *first* option: `Eclipse GlassFish 5.1.0`

I have unzipped the `glassfish-5.1.0.zip` file

Now about to startup the server, through the console:

- In `C:\something\glassfish\5.1.0`

using the `bin\asadmin start-domain` command

```
> bin\asadmin start-domain
Enter master password (3) attempt(s) remain)>
Sorry, incorrect master password, retry
Enter master password (2) attempt(s) remain)>
Sorry, incorrect master password, retry
Enter master password (1) attempt(s) remain)>
Number of attempts (3) exhausted, giving up
Command start-domain failed.
```

I used the `changeit` password and nothing, it according with:

- `C:\something\glassfish\5.1.0\glassfish\docs\index.html`

Where in the `Default Administration Values` section, there is the `Table 1-2 Default Administration Values` and it contains: `Master password` is `changeit`

Even if in `C:\something\glassfish\5.1.0\glassfish\` is executed the command `bin\asadmin start-domain` the same situation happens

Until here observe the two different paths:

- `C:\something\glassfish\5.1.0\bin`
- `C:\something\glassfish\5.1.0\glassfish\bin`

The suggested password does not work.

I have tried with the suggestion in:

- [glassfish master password error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43585247/3665178)

Thus, using `asadmin change-master-password --savemasterpassword=true domain1` for either of the two paths shown above, but always happens:

```
asadmin change-master-password --savemasterpassword=true domain1
Enter the current master password>
Incorrect current master password. You will not be able to change it.
Command change-master-password failed.
```

**Note:** Working with *second* option `Eclipse GlassFish 5.1.0 Web Profile` the command works fine

```
C:\something\glassfish\web-5.1.0\glassfish5
> bin\asadmin start-domain
Waiting for domain1 to start .....
Successfully started the domain : domain1
domain  Location: C:\whiteroom\glassfish\web-5.1.0\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1
Log File: C:\whiteroom\glassfish\web-5.1.0\glassfish5\glassfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log
Admin Port: 4848
Command start-domain executed successfully.
```

**Questions:**

1. Therefore what is missing to accomplish the goal about to startup the server for the first option? What is the correct password?
2. Why the web profile does not ask for a password and yes for the non-web profile?